# query: has_many where all the child fields are nil

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using Rails 3.2 with ActiveRecord and MySQL and I have models with one to many association:

```
class Author
  has_many :books
end

class Book
  belongs_to :author
  attr_accessible :review
end
```

I want to find authors that have **all** the books without review. I tried:

```
Author.includes(:books).where('book.review IS NIL')
```

but is obviously didn't work, because it finds authors that have **at least one** book without review. What query should I use?

Comment: Why book has_one :author, and not belong_to :author?

Comment: @WRz I've corrected the association, thanks :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL is quite simple:

```
SELECT authors.name, count(books.review is not null) 
FROM authors LEFT JOIN books ON (authors.id=books.author_id) 
GROUP BY authors.name
HAVING count(books.review) == 0
```

Translating it to the AR query language may take me some time...
OK, so it seems to look like this:

```
Author.count('books.review', joins: :books, select: 'name', 
              group:'name', having: 'count_books_review=0')
```

As for me SQL looks much less weird then this ;-)

Comment: That's the first time I see this usage of `.count` method :). Could you post a link to the docs? The only usage I'm accustomed to is just `Book.count` with no arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Basing on the WRz answer I prepared my own query:

```
Author.joins(:books).group('authors.id').having("count(books.reviews)=0")
```

It's better suited for me, because it returns an AR Relation (and WRz's query returns a Hash).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Author.joins(:books).where('books.review is null')
```

edit: This will fetch all the authors with at least one book with no review. I just realized your question is a bit different.

It would be something like this.

```
Authors.joins(:books).select('authors.*, count(books.id) as
total_books, count('books.review is null')
as books_without_review.group('authors.id').having(total_books ==
books_without_review)
```

P.S: This is not the exact syntax and it is untested

Comment: I'm afraid that this is a similar case as the one I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code.

```
class Author
  has_many :books
end

class Book
  belongs_to :author
  attr_accessible :review
end

authors = Author.all.collect do |author|
            if author.books.where(:review => nil).size == author.books.size
              author
            end
          end

authors.compact!
```

After this code, authors will be an array containing all the authors having all the books unreviewed. Also note that I changed the author association in `Book` model to `belongs_to` instead of `has_one`. It is always a good practice to have `has_many` relation on one side and `belongs_to` association on the other side.

Comment: I would like to avoid fetching all the data to memory and filtering it there. I believe it should be done in the db-side.