# Find only records which have all deleted associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, left-join

The question goes as RoR but I guess the question applies more on a query level.

I have a model

```
ModelA has_many ModelB
```

and I'm using `paranoid` gem in both of them.

I am trying to find out all the `ModelA` which have either no `ModelB` associated or all its `ModelB` have been deleted (therefore `deleted_at` is not NULL).

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677246/left-outer-join-and-an-additional-where-clause), I was able to achieve the desired result, but reading the query it does not make much sense to me how it is working.

```
ModelA.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN model_bs ON model_bs.model_a_id = model_as.id AND model_bs.deleted_at IS NULL')
  .where('model_bs.model_a_id IS NULL')
  .group(model_as.id)
```

As mentioned, reading this query it does not make sense to me because the joins condition I'm using is also being as null on the where clause afterwards.

Can someone please help me out getting the query properly set and if this is the right way to go, explain me how does the query breakdown into the right result.

**Update:**

As mentioned on a comment below, after some raw sql I managed to understand what was going on. Also, wrote my AR solution as to make it more clear (at least from my perspective)

**Breaking it down:**

This query represents a regular left outer join, which returns all models on the left independently if there is an association on the right.

```
ModelA.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN model_bs ON model_bs.model_a_id = model_as.id')
```

Adding the extra condition in the join

`AND model_bs.deleted_at IS NULL`

will return the rows with `ModelB` attributes available if there is one associated, else will return one row with only the `ModelA`.

Applying over these rows the
`.where('model_bs.model_a_id IS NULL')` will keep only rows that have no associated models.

**Note:**
In this case, using the attribute `model_a_id` or any other attribute of `model_b` will work, but if going this way, I'd recommend using an attribute that if the association exists, its always going to be there. Otherwise you might end up with wrong results.

Finally, the AR that I've ended up by using to translate what I wanted:

```
ModelA.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN model_bs ON model_bs.model_a_id = model_as.id AND model_bs.deleted_at IS NULL')
  .group('model_as.id')
  .having('count(model_bs.id) = 0')
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, you can check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15660222/580346

Comment: After posting here I kept on searching for the explanation. A bit of raw sql instead of AR, helped me to understand the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try this way i have tested it in `mysql` you can verify it with `PG`

```
ModelA.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN model_bs ON model_bs.model_a_id = model_as.id')
  .group('model_as.id')
  .having('SUM(CASE WHEN model_bs.deleted_at IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS OCT = 0')
```

Comment: Please check my updated answer, as I've answered to myself before.
Why would I rather go for a cased sum when I can simply add one more condition in the joins?

This doesn't seem to be the way to go.

Comment: @rpbaltazar are you sure your updated is working as per your requirement? i guess it returns only modelA having no modelB it will not return your `modelA` which is having all modelB is deleted.

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is working. The use of the joins with the predicate `AND model_bs.deleted_at IS NULL` gives me that. If there is any association with `deleted_at` NULL it will return a row per association, else it will return a row without the association. Therefore, when I group by `model_as.id`, the `model_bs.id` is either there and is greater or equal to 1 or not.

Comment: @rpbaltazar it is good if you put your sample data with output using your query? and elaborate this query.  Because as per my comment only data is output. not your required as `find out all the ModelA which have either no ModelB associated or all its ModelB have been deleted (therefore deleted_at is not NULL)`